# Cypress error message "bash: ./node_modules/.bin/cypress: No such file or directory"

Tags: cypress

**
When I use ./node_modules/.bin/cypress. I have an error message while Gitbash and powershel are exist**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in Exact Directory

```
cd /your/project/path
```

and then try

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress open
```